# Handsontable how redraw col borders after insert new row

Tags: border, handsontable

I have handson table, and my same col have custom borders

customBorders:  [{

```
              range: {from:{row:0,col:5},to:{row:_rowsCount,col:7}},
              left: {width: 2,color: '#5292F7'},
              right: {width: 2,color: '#5292F7'}
```

}]

afterCreateRow my borders don't redraw and last row don't have my custom borders

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call to the render function.

```
myHoT.render();
```

Comment: I call after create new row, but last row not have my border

Answer (score 0):

```
afterCreateRow : function(index, amount, source) {
 _rowsCount += 1;
 handsontable.updateSettings({
  customBorders:  [{range: {from:{row:0,col:5},to:{row:_rowsCount,col:7}},
                    left: {width: 2,color: '#5292F7'},
                    right: {width: 2,color: '#5292F7'}
                  }],
 });
 handsontable.render();
});
```

NOT WORK!